# Making content within the iframe to fit within view-port in Mobile

Tags: iframe

I have a old html code, which is not responsive. 
This content has to be fit in iframe in mobile, though its not responsive can we make it fit on the view-port, without horizontal scrollbar.

[Example](https://punithnpg.github.io/) of page with iframe and old code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>IFrame Issue</title>
<style>
iframe{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <iframe src="https://punithnpg.github.io/query/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your efforts

Comment: https://punithnpg.github.io/